# jQuery - Auto Suggest - focusout()

Tags: jquery, focusout

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/iPIW1AvQUrThidzA3bw9?p=preview

The requirement is to create multiple auto-suggest input boxes that show up only when a user starts typing in an input field. Clicking a value from the input box should populate that input with the selected value and hide the auto-suggest.
The code I wrote works until here.

I am also trying to hide the auto-suggest box when a user starts typing, then changes focus to a different inputbox. When I implement `focusout()` to do that, the click on the suggest dropdown does not work.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The work around is to use focusin() instead of focusout() at least in this case. So, it would look like

> $('.autoSelectInput').focusout(function(){
>     $autoSelectDropdown.hide(); });